# Return multiple values with NSPredicate

Tags: iphone, core-data

I am using NSPredicate to query a Core Data store. I have an atribute of type NSNumber. I want to get all atributes which equal 1.

I have tried:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"attribute == %i", i];
```

Where i = 1.

This works but it only returns the first object with the matching attribute. I want ALL objects with this attribute when it is equal to 1.

Where am I going wrong? I tried putting ALL in front of the query but that caused a crash.

Update:

This is my full code:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Person"
                                          inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
[fetchRequest setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];

NSNumber *attributeValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"attribute == %@",
                          attributeValue];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *fetchResults = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                                                 error:&error];

return [fetchResults objectAtIndex:0];
```

And then:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [self queryContextWithQuery:nil];
NSLog(@"%@", dict);
```

The log only shows 1 out of the 3 possible objects it should show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem wasn't with the query. It was with how I was returning the result. I modified the method to return an array instead of a dictionary and changed:

```
return [fetchResults objectAtIndex:0];
```

To:

```
return fetchResults;
```

And now I am getting the correct results.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSNumber *attributeValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"myAttr == %@",
        attributeValue];
```

Comment: @kmcgrady Mmm try changing the like for ==, not sure why you would get that error.

Comment: That works like my original code. It only returns 1 object instead of the 3 that match the criteria.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
NSNumber *attributeValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"attribute == %@",
        attributeValue];
```

Comment: I'm getting the same result with that. When I log the NSDictionary returned it only shows 1 object when it should show 3 which match the criteria.